# Industrial schematics

Tags: luatex, circuitikz, metapost, tikz-circuit-lib

I'm investigating if it is possible to generate electrical schematics for industrial machinery with the LaTeX ecosystem. They are quite different from electronic circuits because are developed sequentially. Here is a typical page drawn with [QElectrotech](http://qelectrotech.org/) (the only open source package I found for such purpose):

[image: The schematic of a digital input module]

These are my requirements:

1. the schematic can span several pages (let's say up to 50);
2. adding new symbols must be easy;
3. should be introspectable (if possible) to leave the doors opened for addition of generated contents (wire numbering, cross reference, terminals and a lot of stuff can be automatically generated);
4. the result must be easy to be embedded in a LaTeX document.

I checked some existent solution but I'd like to have advices from more seasoned people:

1. METAPOST
   It is a pleasure to use and [MakeCirc](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/makecirc) yet provides a base, but I fear scalability issues and I don't like the way dynamic text is handled.
2. [Circuitikz](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz)
   Seems to be the quickest way to get started but I'm scared of TeX language and I don't have any idea on how introspection can be implemented.
3. The circuits library of TikZ PGF
   I found no documentation and from what I understood it provides no benefit to circuitikz other than being a core library.
4. [pst-circ](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-circ/)
   For this use case, I don't see any advantage over circuitikz.
5. [Circuit macros](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/circuit_macros)
   Not tested: I'd prefer to avoid having to learn two new languages (m4 and pic) if there are no clear advantages.

Also, this application seems to be a good candidate for LuaTEX, but I lack a general overview of the interaction between the components, hence I don't know if it is better (or even possible) have LaTeX embedding Lua code that generates circuitikz macros or a Lua program that calls METAPOST for symbols and TeX for labels or Lua embedded into circuitikz in some way to provide introspection.

Comment: This is not exactly a question as you might imagine but a feature request. The circuit library of TikZ/PGF is 30 pages long in [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf) with a comprehensive list of commands. Also, these are all circuit libraries which are not necessarily suitable for wiring diagrams. Many high voltage elements are not inclcuded , as expected, together with other elements such as contactors etc.

Comment: @percusse: thank you, I totally missed it. Anyway I don't know if this is a feature request because I don't know if it is even possible to use something yet existent to implement what requested.

Comment: As it stands, this is simply too large an area to form a reasonable question in the site format. Of course, if someone does the work then we can reopen and answer ...